# django, create two related model instances

Tags: database, django, constraints

I have Thread and Post model.

Post has a foreignKey to Thread (thread has many posts)
Thread has a OneToOneKey to Post (thread has one special post)

Upon a Post form submission, I create Thread and Post object.

```
t = Thread.objects.create()
p = Post.objects.create(thread=t)

t.special_post = p
t.save()
```

Is there a way to enforce the constraint(thread should have a special_post, post should have a thread) in DB level in django?

Comment: `null=False` and `blank=False` in the model should do that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) of django model class.It looks like normal python class inherits but it establishes a one-to-one relationship between `Thread` and `Post` automatically:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    ...

class Post(Thread):
    ...
```

After the change, maybe you need do manipulations only with Post model, you can access thread by `post_instance.thread`.